# How can I import configurable products to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm successfully imported `simple products` to **Magento 2.x**, but for `configurable products` don't know how to prepare the template `.xlsx|csv` file.

Any suggestions on this, how to prepare the template for `configurable products`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to prepare the csv file like the same as simple products.

Add one more column called `configurable_variations` and specify the child sku's only for the parent item. For the child items, this field will be empty.

> Example:
>
> sku=WJ06-XS-Blue,size=XS|sku=WJ06-S-Blue,size=S|sku=WJ06-M-Blue,size=M|sku=WJ06-L-Blue,size=L|sku=WJ06-XL-Blue,size=XL|sku=WJ06-XS-Green,size=XS|sku=WJ06-S-Green,size=S|sku=WJ06-M-Green,size=M|sku=WJ06-L-Green,size=L|sku=WJ06-XL-Green,size=XL|sku=WJ06-XS-Purple,size=XS|sku=WJ06-S-Purple,size=S|sku=WJ06-M-Purple,size=M|sku=WJ06-L-Purple,size=L|sku=WJ06-XL-Purple,size=XL

Comment: I tried same as above and it's created the parent product without child products. Even though I gave existing `SKU` also, but not taken. I gave dynamic **configurable_variations** => `sku=LTR-Sample-03 Mil,pouch_thickness=3 Mil|sku=LTR-Sample-05 Mil,pouch_thickness=5 Mil|sku=LTR-Sample-07 Mil,pouch_thickness=7 Mil`

Comment: @Bojjaiah , do you remember what you were doing wrong here?

Comment: @Milos Hmmm no, sorry.